# Plant with pink five-petalled flowers and waxy ovate leaves

Tags: identification, flowering

Please help identify this plant. The cutting rooted and it's now flowering,  but I have no idea what it is.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is [Catharanthus roseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catharanthus_roseus), commonly known as the Madagascar periwinkle or rosy periwinkle. It is native and endemic to Madagascar, but grown elsewhere as an ornamental and medicinal plant, a source of the drugs vincristine and vinblastine, used to treat cancer. Other English names include Vinca, Cape periwinkle, rose periwinkle, rosy periwinkle, and "old-maid". It was formerly included in the genus Vinca as Vinca rosea.

[image]